# use chrome tab capture without Active tab permissions/ get Active tab permissions without user input

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am stuck with this problem for quite some time now. I want to use chrome tabCapture API to automatically record tabs without user input. I am completely fine with using all kinds of permissions. I tried using <all_urls> permission too but I'm unable to gain Active tab permission for tab capture. I also tried sending a message using content_scripts but still, I'm unable to get active tab permissions. Is there some way to get this done or some workaround this problem? This is the error I'm facing.

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

Also, If I ported my extension to firefox, will it still require me to get active tab permission or <all_urls> will work fine? By reading the Documentation, I inferred it should be fine.

Comment: What error message do you see in your extension's console when trying to do so?

Comment: @Asesh Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.capture: Extension has not been invoked for the current page (see activeTab permission). Chrome pages cannot be captured.

Comment: As the error says you can't do it without an explicit user gesture. This is intentional to prevent data exfiltration. The only workaround extensions can use is `chrome.debugger` API to send [Page.captureScreenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) command.